# Netbeans x PHP x Chrome - XDebug not working after El Capitan update

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, osx-elcapitan

After updating from Yosemite to El Capitan, breakpoints are not working in Netbeans anymore, I keep getting this error:

Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)...

Anything i should change on my php.ini / httpd.conf files after updating?

Here is my xdebug section on php.ini:

```
[xdebug] 
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the El Captain update created a new php.ini file and copied the older one as 'php.ini-5.2-previous'.

After i edited the current php.ini with the xdebug information i could fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for anwering.I already configured the new php.ini file by adding the missing xdebug lines. phpinfo() shows xdebug is installed, but when i try to debug with Netbeans, the same error occurs "waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)"